# WooCommerce Subscriptions get Billing Interval & ID

Tags: hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using a stripe "wc_gateway_stripe_process_response" to get payment information.  What is needed is what is the payment interval for that product and what the user's subscription id is.   This is the code I have to date:

```
 function woointerface_ProcessOrder($order_id) 
  {         
  $order               = new WC_Order( $order_id );                  
  $TransactionId       = $order->get_transaction_id();              
  $szOrderId           = $order->get_order_number();

  // Find all products associated with this order
 $order_data          = $order->get_data();                        
 $order_billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();                
 $payment_method      = $order->get_payment_method_title();         
 $PaymentDate         = $order->get_date_paid();
 $OrderNumber         = $order->get_order_number();

 $User      = get_user_by( 'email', $order_billing_email );             
 $FirstName = $User->first_name;
 $LastName  = $User->last_name;
 $UserId    = $User->ID;
 $PayerName = $FirstName . ' ' . $LastName;

  $items  = $order->get_items();
  foreach( $items as $item_id => $product )
    {   
  $ProductName         = $product->get_name();        
  $ProductId           = $product->get_product_id();  
  $PaymentAmount       = $product->get_total();     
  $ProductIndex        = wc_get_product($ProductId);

  if(! WC_Subscriptions_Product::is_subscription( $ProductIndex ) ) 
    continue;

 $UserSubscriptionId = ??
 $BillingCycle = ??


// Store in local table.

 }
```

Looking for how to get the User subscription id and billing cycle for this order.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for billing and Id.   The following calls give you the billing and user subscription id information:

```
   $BillingCycle       = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval($ProductIndex);  // how many times within the period to bill 
   $BillingPeriod      = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period($ProductIndex);    // Month/week/Year

   $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions(array('order_id' => $order->id, 'product_id' => $ProductId));
   if (!empty($subscriptions)) 
   {
   $subscription = array_pop($subscriptions);
   $PaidSubscriptionId = $subscription->id;
   }
```

Comment: Can you please define something about '$productIndex'

Comment: It is the product Id. I called it the index, since it is in a loop and there may be more than one product in the cart.